# How to read headers from a websocket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter

i try to send an information on the header of a webSocket, and read it on the server on connection.
things like:

Client code is as simple as:

```
ws = await WebSocket.connect('ws://localhost.com:36485', headers: {
        'codeName': 'Something',
      },);
```

the server code:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 36485 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

  console.log(ws.upgradeReq.headers);

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

});
```

the exception that i have is :

Type Error: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

Comment: `function connection(ws, req) { console.log(req.headers); }`

Comment: Which websocket module are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using this [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) module on NPM, then way you get access to the headers like this (taken directly from [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)):

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function(ws, req) {
  console.log(req.headers);
});
```

Comment: yes am using ws and i tried your solution but it gives me that:

{
  'user-agent': 'Dart/2.5 (dart:io)',
  connection: 'Upgrade',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
  'content-length': '0',
  'sec-websocket-version': '13',
  host: '192.168.1.111:34263',
  'sec-websocket-extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits',
  'sec-websocket-key': 'CTmyH2GK40xgg/330N+wvQ==',
  upgrade: 'websocket'
}
Connected ...

I can't see the information i passed on the client connection.

Comment: Which websocket library are you using in the client (please provide a link to the library)?  What is the client?  Is it a browser?  Or some other environment?

Comment: am using web_socket_channel on a flutter app

Comment: @yassineyass - Well, you need to look at the doc for how you set headers.  You are clearly seeing the headers that are on the request which is what your question asked how to do.  The remaining problem is that your desired header isn't being included.  This is apparently an issue with the webSocket library for flutter and how you are using it.  I'm not seeing any doc that shows you can set a header with the connection request the way you are attempting with the `web_socket_channel` 1.1.0 library.  Do you see any doc like that?

Comment: @yassineyass - This is the [`.connect()` doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/web_socket_channel/latest/web_socket_channel/WebSocketChannel/WebSocketChannel.connect.html) I see.  Only a URI argument, not a header argument.

Comment: thanks for referring to this, i came to realize that the library has no way to include headers in the connection.
i'll check if there is any other libraries with a solution, cause i need to pass infos before accepting connection.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help, for some reason its not working with 'ws' but its working fine with 'webSoket'.

```
var webSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');
wsServer.on('request', function(request){
  console.log(request.httpRequest.headers['codename']);
}
```